# check old password and updating a new password using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi i have this page change password. I want to check the current password that matches into the database. then saving the new password on it. However i got it compared in the old password that checks on the database. Im wondering that when i click the change password button there is a pop up dialog box that says confirm password change, and i dont know where that pop up dialog came from. And also my saveNewPass code will not work. Can someone help me figured this out?. Here is my code below.

My controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Change_password extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('users_model', 'um');
    $this->load->library('session');
    if(!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')){
      redirect('login');
    }
  }




  public function change(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassword', 'New Password', 'required|matches[re_password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('re_password', 'Retype Password', 'required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
       $this->data['title'] = 'Change Password';
        $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');
        $this->data['id'] = $sessionData['id'];
        $this->data['username'] = $sessionData['username'];
        $this->data['type'] = $sessionData['type'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('pages/change_password');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }else{
      $query = $this->um->checkOldPass(sha1($this->input->post('old_password')));
      if($query){
        $query = $this->um->saveNewPass(sha1($this->input->post('newpassword')));
        if($query){
          redirect('change_password');
        }else{
          redirect('change_password');
        }
      }

    }
  }

  public function index(){
    $this->data['title'] = 'Change Password';
    $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');
    $this->data['id'] = $sessionData['id'];
    $this->data['username'] = $sessionData['username'];
    $this->data['type'] = $sessionData['type'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('pages/change_password');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
}
```

My model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_model extends CI_Model {


   public function checkOldPass($old_password){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $row    = $query->row();
    echo "Old Password : ".$old_password."<br>";
    echo "From DB : ".$row->password."<br>";
    die;

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      $row = $query->row();
      if($old_password == $row->password){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  public function saveNewPass($new_pass){
    $array = array(
            'password'=>$new_pass
            );
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
    $query = $this->db->update('users');
    if($query){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }  



}
```

and my views

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="homepage_content">
    <div>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">View Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'change_password'?>">Change Password</a></li>
        <?php if($type == "Root"): ?>
        <li><a href="">Create New Account</a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <li class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url().'logout'?>">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>welcome <?php echo $username; ?></p>
    <p>Account Type <?php echo $type; ?></p>
    <br />
    <form action="<?php echo base_url().'change_password/change'?>" method="post">
      <div class="errors">
        <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
      </div>
      <p><input type="password" name="old_password" placeholder="Current Password: " class="form-control"></p><br />
      <p><input type="password" name="newpassword" placeholder="New Password: " class="form-control"></p><br />
      <p><input type="password" name="re_password" placeholder="Retype New Password: " class="form-control"></p><br />
      <input type="submit" value="change password" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is muchly appreciated

Comment: That Popup is of your browser, You must know browser ask you remind password when you login with new user. It do not affect on your code or functionality.

Comment: Then why there is a popup box?

Comment: browser saves your passwords in his history, While you try to change any saved User's password it asks you for "Save New Password"

Comment: if you are using Firefox you can get saved password in options-> security-> saved password.

Comment: what to do with the options uncheck it?

Comment: you said on this comment
if you are using Firefox you can get saved password in options-> security-> saved password.
then i go to options -> secruity-> save password. then i uncheck it

Comment: forget about that popup message for now.

Comment: can you help me with the code?

Comment: what exact problem you are facing with code ?

Comment: in the save new pass it will not properly save to the respective id

Comment: Do you have any unique id col in table  user /

Comment: yes the id in my fields is unique

Comment: if you are getting True values in checkOldPass then return that field in checkOldPass and use that id in where condition of saveNewPass method

Comment: this is my code in savenew pass

 public function saveNewPass($new_pass){
    $array = array(           
            'password'=>$new_pass
            );
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
    $query = $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'))->update('users', $array);
    if($query){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try following code to check `username` and `old_password` are matching,

```
public function checkOldPass($old_password)
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->where('password', $old_password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

if `username` and `old_password` are matching the above function will return `1` and if `username` and `old_password` are not matching the above function will return `0`

EDIT :

```
public function saveNewPass($new_pass)
{
    $data = array(
           'password' => $new_pass
        );
    $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
    return true;
}
```

To check Password and Confirm Password, use JavaScript/ Jquery.

JavaScript :

```
function chkPwd(a)
    {
        // let Pswd is ID of password and cPswd is ID of confirm password text Box
        var newPwd = document.getElementById('Pswd').value;
        var cPwd = document.getElementById('cPswd').value;
        if(newPwd != cPwd)
        {
            document.getElementById('cPswd').focus();
            document.getElementById('cPswd').value="";
            document.getElementById('err').innerHTML="Passwords are Not Matching";
        }   
    }
```

Comment: hmmm thats the same as mine you only change inside the if to return 1 else return 0

Comment: Hi your code works well thanks for that. I have a question if i have to input the current password which is match at the database then type the new password then re type the new password. when i input the current password the new password then did not match the retype password it will save then update the database. How to add a validation on this? pls help

Comment: Do you want to check new_password == confirm_password ?

Comment: hey my password and confirm password are ok i check them using the codeigniter form validation. My problem is when i input the correct current password then input the new password but wrong retype new password it will save to the database. I want that when i input the correct current password then input the new password but wrong retype new password it will validate.

Comment: sorry unable to get your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
public function changePassword()
{
    $pass=$this->input->post('old_password');
    $npass=$this->input->post('newpassword');
    $rpass=$this->input->post('re_password');
    if($npass!=$rpass){
        return "false";
    }else{
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('email',$this->session->userdata('admin_email'));
        $this->db->where('password',md5($pass));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $data = array(
                           'password' => md5($npass)
                        );
            $this->db->where('email', $this->session->userdata('admin_email'));
            $this->db->update('users', $data); 
            return "true";
        }else{
            return "false";
        }
    }
}
```