# How to fetch record from database and send it to email using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to fetch the record from database and send that record on email?.I am able to receive the data from database but not able to send that record on email.I am getting email on my email id but its totally blank.$pass['pass'] variable is retrieving record from database.I am able to display record on screen using print_r($pass) and passed this variable to email->message($pass) but its not working.

Please help me in this.

**Controller**

```
$emailTo = $this->input->post('email');

    $this->load->model('Model_login');
    $pass['pass']=$this->Model_login->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);


        $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'mail.demo.com',
        'smtp_port' => 25,
        'smtp_user' => 'noreply@demo.com', 
        'smtp_pass' => 'demo#@123', 
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
      );


           $this->load->library('email', $config);
           $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");  
           $this->email->from('noreply@demo.com'); 
           $this->email->to($emailTo);
           $this->email->subject('there');
           $this->email->message($pass);
         if($this->email->send())
         {


       redirect('Welcome/index');

         }
         else
         {
          show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
         }
```

**model**

```
public function forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo)
   {

$this->db->select('password');
$this->db->from('admin_user');
$this->db->where('email',$emailTo);
$this->db->limit(1);

    $query=$this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
    return $query->result();    
    }
    else
      {
      return FALSE;
   }
```

Comment: because `$pass` is an array, if you did `$this->email->message($pass['pass']);` it would probably work

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried that also but  i am not getting value on email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `->row()` to fetch single row

In **MODEL**

```
$query=$this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
{
$val = $query->row();
return $val->password;    
}
```

Just use `$pass` to get your password

In **CONTROLLER**

```
$pass=$this->Model_login->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: Yes Mr.Saty its working.I got a output on email. thanks for your reply.

Comment: But what was the issue on my code? Can you help me in this?

Comment: Issue is that you are fetching array of object while using `->result()` from database In models and in controller you assing that array of object into `$pass` array i.e `$pass['pass']`

Comment: Yeah right,Mr.Saty can help me  how to change the password? If you have any link so please share so that can go throw it

Comment: no email.I have created a page change password from there i have to change password and that will update on database.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523631/check-old-password-and-updating-a-new-password-using-codeigniter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106432/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-saty).